# Can't visit object member variable in object C

Tags: objective-c, variables, cocos2d-iphone

I have a very weird issue .I defined two class :A and B,In B,It have a member variable NSArray*bullets,In A ,It have a member variable B*b,Now in one of A's function,I tried to visit b.bullets,But it tells me "the bullets not find on type of... ",I have written 
"@property bullets" in B.h and "@synthesize bullets=_bullets" in B.m,Any help is very previous 
for me,thanks

[image: enter image description here:The HelloWorldLayer class is the B]

Comment: Please post the code instead of screen shot. Please also post the header and the relevant portion of the .m file.

Comment: poor problem description + no source code = small chance of a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

`@property bullets;` is not enough.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) will tell you everything you need to know about properties.

To quote, this is the correct syntax:

`@property (attributes) type name;`